# How to find the number of records affected by a CDatabase transaction?

Tags: sql, database, mfc

Is there (simple) way in a `CDatabase` (against an MDB file), after `BeginTrans`, to check how many records will be affected by an `ExecuteSQL` call that does a `DELETE`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `ALTER`? In `CDaoDatabase` there is `GetRecordsAffected` - but I can't find anything similar for `CDatabase`.

I was (previously) using the number of affected records as a level of confirmation that my SQL was doing what I intended before either committing or rolling back the transaction. However I haven't been able to replicate that functionality since changing DB API tech.

I could probably auto-formulate a `SELECT` statement with the same `WHERE` parameters and count the results - but that is a lot of work, and I was hoping I missing something simple...